# How to calculate distribution of sine of a random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to prove $$
\int_{\Xi} \exp \left(\|\xi\|^{a}\right) \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d} \xi)<\infty,
$$ where the random variable $\xi$ complies with the distribution of $\sin(X)$ with $X \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$.

I figured out how to calculate the first two order moments. Just wondering how to calculate the distribution of $\sin(X)$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Can I somehow figure out the distribution with the help of the chance of variable method?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448703/distribution-of-y-sin-x-when-x-is-normal

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. However, the closed-form solution from the link is not the correct answer and the second answer only provides first two moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that $\exp(\|\xi\|^a)$ is bounded, and you are integrating with respect to a finite measure.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint. I guess I could find an upper bound of the exponential term and the function is measurable so that it corresponds to the definition of integrable.